# Detect valid credit card number algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50, credit-card

I just enrolled in the online CS50 course and doing the pset1 about detecting valid credit card number. However, my algorithm does not work well as I expected. I used debugging tool to see step by step result, as long as variable i run from 1 to 9 it works perfectly, all values are added to the sum correctly. But when it comes to i = 10 and so on, the numNotSquared got assigned -8 and numSquared got assigned -16 and it keeps like that until the end of the number. Please help me with that, thank you.

```
// Headers and libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt user for card number
    long cardNumber = get_long("Enter card number: ");

    // Get the length of input
    int length = floor(log10(cardNumber)) + 1;

    // Range validation
    if (length < 13 || length > 16)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

    int numSquared = 0;
    int numNotSquared = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    // Algorithm to detect valid card
    // Based on Luhn's algorithm (https://lab.cs50.io/cs50/labs/2020/x/credit/)
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {
        // If digit is on odd position then mutiply by two
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            {
                numSquared = ((int)(cardNumber / pow(10, length - i)) % 10) * 2;
            }
            // If the total is >= 10, then sum the products' digit
            if (numSquared >= 10)
            {
                sum += ((numSquared % 10) + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                sum += numSquared;
            }
        }
        // If digit is on even position then add to the sum
        else
        {
            numNotSquared = (int)(cardNumber / pow(10, length - i)) % 10;
            sum += numNotSquared;
        }
    }

    // Find remainder of (total / 10)
    if (sum % 10 == 0)
    {
        if (floor(cardNumber / pow(10, length - 1)) == 4)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
        }
        else
        {
            int firstTwoDigits = floor(cardNumber / pow(10, length - 2));

            if (firstTwoDigits == 34 || firstTwoDigits == 37)
            {
                printf("AMEX\n");
            }
            else if (firstTwoDigits == 51 || firstTwoDigits == 52 || firstTwoDigits == 53 || firstTwoDigits == 54 || firstTwoDigits == 55)
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Handling the card number as an integer and mixing floating point math with integer math is a really bad idea. Treat the number as a string of digits and work with each digit separately, it's much easier and it most importantly will not cause rounding errors.

Comment: Never use integer variables for card or phone numbers, or PINs. Please use a string. Apart from the ease of handling, if the number begins with one or more zeros how will you know they have been entered?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try to solve the problem by store the cc number as a string. I am following the lesson from the course and they suggested using a long variable to store the input, and I cannot figure out what went wrong when the loop run to the 10th time and so on. This is the link to the problem: https://lab.cs50.io/cs50/labs/2020/x/credit/

Comment: Also, this problem is to teach learners how to think to solve a problem (in this case is detect valid cc number as a long). The function get_long is from the cs50 library and it will prompt again until user type a number with length between 13 and 16. So the validation part if user type characters, number begin with zero or other edge cases is not the main focus of this.

Comment: The C standard allows a `long` to be 32 bits, which gives it a maximum value 2147483647. That means that 9 digits will always work, and the 10th digit will work if it's a 0 or 1, and sometimes if it's 2.